# Make NSWindow appear in front when used with FireBreath

Tags: objective-c, macos, firebreath

I am using FireBreath to create a cross browser plugin which makes use of some native libraries for the respective platform (some .NET based DLLs for Windows and Objective-C based dylibs/frameworks for Mac). The library displays a UI which should ultimately appear in front of other windows (specially in front of the browser window). For Windows, I am using the win32 API to pass in the window handler and to bring it to foreground. This is working fine at the moment. However, I am currently unable to find a suitable workaround for Mac, therefore the window always appear behind the browser in Mac. Is there any workaround for this problem ?

I have tried following approaches without much success:

1) Setting the level of NSWindow to a higher value (eg: NSFloatingWindowLevel) and calling orderFront method.

2) Setting activateIgnoringOtherApps property in NSApp and calling makeKeyAndOrderFront method.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps FireBreath is making the OS X applet part be a background application using `LSBackgroundOnly` in `Info.plist`? If that is set, your plugin cannot come to the front, AFAIK...

Comment: An NPAPI plugin does have an Info.plist, but it doesn't affect things like that in the slightest. The issue is that you're in someone else's process and they control all of that stuff

Comment: Yes that is the cause of the problem. Since the native components are invoked by the browser, they are essentially running within the environment provided by the browser. I used a small test app (Cocoa) to test the functionality of the native components and everything is working fine there. The problem occurs when FireBreath plugin is used to invoke the native components using the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for the support. I managed to fix the issue and I am replying here for the completeness of the thread.

This issue was caused by a fundamental fact in Objective-C which had nothing to do with FireBreath. The window object in NSWindow was not initialized (nil) when the methods were invoked to bring it to foreground. Once that was fixed, simply setting the window level to NSFloatingWindowLevel fixed this issue.

Comment: Hi, when you mention that "The window object in NSWindow was not initialized (nil) when the methods were invoked to bring it to foreground". Can you show a little code for it? I guess I am facing the same situation here. I put [[self window] set level ....] in awakeFromNib , is it right? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best bet I can think of would be to launch another process to do your UI stuff and talk across the boundary. I've done this before piping the STDOUT and STDIN to communicate with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have tried communication between processes using piping before, but can we use a separate process to manage the UI ? If possible, would you be able to share some sample code ? Thanks again.

Comment: the seperate process would have to create its own UI and then it could manage it.  It certainly cannot be used to manage the browser's UI... in fact, that's your problem to start with. Your plugin runs in a seperate process from the browser, and thus it cannot manage the browser's UI.  No, I don't have any sample code.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I managed to fix the issue and it was caused by a fundamental mistake at Objective-C level.

On a rather different note, i see you are the primary maintainer of FireBreath. I've been using it for the past 6 months and it has served my project very well. Thanks for your efforts in developing this wonderful framework.